# Deploy front end and backend code on the web

Tags: heroku, deployment, github-pages, netlify

I made an application for an internship. The front end is made using normal html,css,jquery,bootstrap (no framework).The backend is made using node.js and database used in mongodb.

My project structure is

- Web folder-Contains folders like html,css,js.
- Api folder-Contains all my backend code.

Now, I want to deploy this app to the web such that it works same way it is working locally. My front end makes ajax request to node.js server currently.

**How do I deploy such an app**? Also hosting should be free. I know some approaches such as using Netlify or Github Pages on front end and heroku for backend but don't know the detailed approach. Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Netlify makes the process easy. If your project is in a Git repo you can configure [continuous deployment](https://www.netlify.com/docs/#continuous-deployment).

> Each time you push to your Git provider, Netlify runs a build with your tool of choice and deploys the result to our powerful CDN.

In short...

1. Log in at https://app.netlify.com
2. Click **New Site from Git**.
3. Select a Git provider.
4. Select a repo.
5. Configure your build.

Here's a [2-minute video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mN9oI98As_4) walkthrough.